# Reportviewer: Unable to set Interactive height to 0

Tags: winforms, reportviewer, report-viewer2010, reportviewer2008

I am using reportviewer 2010 Winforms

In normal mode, I want the entire report to display in one page only. I read different topics and learnt setting the Interactive height property to zero might do the trick.

I believe I could set the INterative height by clicking on a tablix -> In Properties window, there's a Size which has Width and height. However when I set the height to 0, it reverts back to the previous inches which was there before.

I need help with how to set the Interactive page height? Is this set at report level or for each tablix inside the report?

I believe the width and height setting in Report => Report properties is for physical rendering (PDf) and not for logical rendering (Html in normal mode).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, I was able to figure it out. I had to bring up the Report properties by clicking somewhere outside the report in the rdlc file. In the properties, I was able to find Interactiveheight and I set it to 0.